# Vuetify 3 v-data-table v-icon conditionally

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frameworks, vuetify.js

i cannot render a conditionally v-icon in a v-data-table in VUETIFY 3  , based on a value 1 or 0 , in vuetify 2 it's easy and in more than two ways but in vuetify 3 it's not rendering.

Show v-icons in vuetify 3 based on a condition v-if v-else , i've tryied many ways ( v-if , v-if [ in vuetify 2 it`s working] ) ..... thank you in advance

```
<v-data-table
        :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        class="elevation-1"
        :search="search"
        dense
      >
        <template v-slot:items.active="{ item }">
          <v-icon v-if="item.active == 1" size="small"
            >mdi-pencil </v-icon
          >
          <v-icon v-else size="small"
            >mdi-delete</v-icon
          >
        </template>

       
    </v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the condition you want to apply here?

In Vuetify for accessing the the item value in the template of v-data-table use `item.raw`.

So if you want to display on condition of your row, give

`<v-icon v-if="item.raw.YOUR_PROPERTY == 'VALUE'" size="small">mdi-pencil </v-icon>`